# Can't get Json android

Tags: java, android, json

I want output json, but I have error

```
06-02 23:10:26.110: W/System.err(23235): org.json.JSONException: Value data of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-02 23:10:26.116: W/System.err(23235):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-02 23:10:26.117: W/System.err(23235):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:158)
06-02 23:10:26.117: W/System.err(23235):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:171)
```

I create my code whith example, its my json:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "users_information": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "active": "1",
            },
{
                "id": "2",
                "active": "1",
            }]}}
```

It's my code:

```
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject("data");

                 JSONArray userInform = data.getJSONArray("users_information");

                 for(int i = 0; i < userInform.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = userInform.getJSONObject(i);
 Log.e("id ", c.getString("id"));
}
```

Comment: how are you getting the json ? JSONObject data = new JSONObject("data");

Comment: @r7v aaaaaa.....thenk a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String data = "{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "users_information": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "active": "1",
            },
{
                "id": "2",
                "active": "1",
            }]}}"
```

parse Json

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(data);

                 JSONArray userInform = data.getJSONArray("users_information");

                 for(int i = 0; i < userInform.length(); i++) {
JSONObject c = userInform.getJSONObject(i);
 Log.e("id ", c.getString("id"));
}
```

The string data json can be replaced by the JSON received from backend

Answer (score 1):

I dont recommend json deserialization like this. Try using at least Gson library. With it you will can create class with same structure like your json and it will parse in single line.

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject("data");
```

You have to place the JSON String where "data" is placed. "data" is just a string and no json like you posted in your example.

If for any reason "data" is your string reference to your JSON String, then you accidentally added the quotes (") which let android interpret it as a String not a reference to a String.

Comment: For test purposes just build a String object with the content of your example JSON and pass it in the JSONObject instantiation

Comment: (PseudoCode) String data = "{status:success}" ; JSONObject pObject = new JSONObject (data) ;